# Find 4 if a given array has 4 consecutive values using functions (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops

A quick disclaimer before you read ahead, this is a question regarding my homework and some of these requirements will be oddly specific

I am writing a code that takes the number of values from the user and this will be the array length. Then it will ask the user to input their numbers into the array. Then it uses a function to determine if the given array contains 4 of the same values consecutively.

This is an example output

```
//example 1
Enter the number of values: 8
Enter the values: 3 4 5 5 5 5 4 5
The list has consecutive fours

//example 2
Enter the number of values: 9
Enter the values: 3 4 5 8 5 5 4 4 5
The list has no  consecutive fours
```

The problem with my code is that I need to make a function `bool isConsecutiveFour(int values[][4])`for the question to be completed. I have tried that and since the array that I am originally using for the user input is a 1-dimensional array, I don't think I can do it 2 dimensional. When I copy and paste the code all into the main function the code works but once I implement it into a function with the requirements, the code starts to not work as intended. In the place where the function is called, I am aware that there is a expected expression, the thing is that I am unsure on what to put there as the original array is 1D while the one in the given function is 2D.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isConsecultiveFour(int values[][4]);

int main(){

    int x, input;

    cout<<"Enter the number of values: "<< endl;
    cin >> x;

    int arr[x];

    cout<<"Enter the values: "<< endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        cin>>input;

        arr[i] = input;
    }

    cout<<" "<< endl;

    //error on the second bracket states that it is expecting an expression
    isConsecultiveFour(arr[x][]);


return 0;
}

bool isConsecultiveFour(int values[][4]){

    int count = 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]); i++){
       
       if(values[i] == values[i + 1]){
            count++;
       }
   }
   if(count == 4 ){
       cout<<"The list has consecutive fours"<< endl;
   }
   else{
       cout<<"The list has no consecitive fours"<< endl;
   }

   return count;

}
```

Comment: `int arr[x];` is a variable-length array and not allowed in C++. You should use `std::vector<int> arr(x);` instead. What do you expect to happen here: `isConsecultiveFour(arr[x][]);`? `arr[x]` would be an access out of bounds. What does `arr[x][]` mean?

Comment: @jabaa the thing is arr[x] i am not sure what to do with it. The system gave me errors on how it was missing variables so I just put arr[x] (an exisitig array ) there

Comment: You can't write code by trial and error. What do you want to achieve? Why do you have to use the signature `bool isConsecutiveFour(int values[][4])`? You should enable your compiler warnings. `sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0])` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: `int values[][4]` decays to a pointer. `sizeof(values)` is not the number of elements in the array but the size of a pointer. Use a vector to avoid this problem. Why is the function parameter a two dimensional array `int values[][4]`? You are using it as one dimensional array `if(values[i] == values[i + 1]){`.

Comment: Supposed `sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0])` would give you the correct size of the array (what it doesn't) `values[i + 1]` would go out of bounds for the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in your code.

- The main problem regarding variable-length arrays and size of an array in a function can be solved using `std::vector`.
- The function should return a boolean.
- You can leave the loop after the fourth consecutive value
- You have to reset the counter if two consecutive values are different.
- You don't need to flush the buffer with `endl`.
- You should avoid `using namespace std;`.
- The type of a size of a STL container or array is `std::size_t`.
- The end of the loop was off by one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool isConsecutiveFour(std::vector<int> values);

int main(){

    std::size_t x;

    std::cout<<"Enter the number of values: \n";
    std::cin >> x;

    std::vector<int> arr(x);

    std::cout<<"Enter the values: \n";
    for(auto &el : arr){
        std::cin>>el;
    }

    std::cout<<" \n";

    isConsecutiveFour(arr);

    return 0;
}

bool isConsecutiveFour(std::vector<int> values){

   int count = 1;
   for(std::size_t i = 0; i + 1 < values.size(); i++){
       
       if(values[i] == values[i + 1]){
           count++;
       } else {
           count = 1;
       }
       if(count == 4 ){
           std::cout<<"The list has consecutive fours\n";
           return true;
       }
   }
   std::cout<<"The list has no consecitive fours\n";
   return false;
}
```